# коды ошибок cifs mount

Tags: администрирование, mount

Несколько лет на Raspberry при загрузке успешно выполнялось монтирование (из *fstab*) по *cifs* на сервер *nas4free*. Недавно обновил версию ОС и там и там. После этого монтирование перестало работать... :-(

В *dmesg* вижу такое сообщение об ошибке:

```
 CIFS: VFS: cifs mount failed w/return code = -95
```

Гугление результата не дало, так как про код -95 никто не пишет. Что означает этот  код?
Есть ли где-то список всех кодов *mount-cifs*?

И как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Ну а логи на сервере чё говорят? Ну и строку фстаба тоже неплохо бы приложить.

Answer (score 0):

Список кодов ошибок я так и не нашёл.

Но методом научного тыка установил, что нужно было добавить в опции параметр:

```
group=users
```

На сервере действительно есть такая группа и в неё включён пользователь, с логин/пароль, заданным в файле *credentials*. Теперь монтируется без проблем.